# Fancybox link to display another fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Sometimes it makes sense to have a link within a fancybox to launch another fancybox (or load content within the current one).

Say, you have a fancybox error message on login.  You also have a "email me my password" widget that works via a fancybox.  You may want to combine the two to say (in a fancybox):

```
Bad password!
<a href="#forgot-password">Forgot my password!</a>
```

Unfortunately, this will not work.  I considered adding the following js:

```
  $('#fancybox-content a').live('click', function(){
      $(this).fancybox();
  });
```

Surprisingly, this sort of worked:  You have to click on the link *twice* and then the right thing happens.  Ugh.

Finally, I found a hacky ugly work-around (it works!):

```
  $('#fancybox-content a').live('click', function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');  //assume there is a selector inside href
    $.fancybox($(href).html());       //find the html manually and load
  });
```

What is the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is i how i solved this problem in my projects:

```
$('a.fancybox').live("click",function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $.fancybox({href: href}) 
});
```

In this way  you can add fancybox to any current un future A elements with .fancybox class so you don't have to define new events after opening fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 is already using "live", so using class names - `$(".fancybox").fancybox();' - would also work on elements loaded using ajax

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what you are saying.  That the original setup will work in version 2 without any additional code?  Or that I don't need to use 'live' and can use 'click'?

Comment: Add class `fancybox` to your links and use fancybox like in my previous comment. No need for custom click handler

Answer (score -2):

You should be telling elements to open a Fancybox from within your plugin.

Somewhere you have the following ->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_element").fancybox();
});
```

That's a very basic function to open a Fancybox, and not only that, but it will also what to open based on the href of the element. You don't need to do any leg work here.

So if you have ->

```
<a href="#forgot-password">Forgot my password!</a>
```

Simply add an ID, such as 'x' for simplicity ->

```
<a id="x" href="#forgot-password">Forgot my password!</a>
```

Then, enable the Fancybox plugin for this element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_element").fancybox();

  //this is for our new container to fire
  $("#x").fancybox();
});
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: with this <a id="forgot-password" href="#forgot-password">Forgot my password!</a> ... you are targeting the link itself, not the content